# apply display:none to div id based on another id and class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

bit stuck,

how do i hide another class based on another class name?

IF my toggle div id has a class of hide-me  `<div id="toggleDiv" class="hide-me"></div>`

then i want to apply display-none to `div#footer_toggle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($("#toggleDiv").hasClass("hide-me")) {
  $("#footer_toggle").hide()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
 if($('#toggleDiv').hasClass('hide-me'){
    $('#footer_toggle').hide():
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if('#toggleDiv').hasClass('hide-me'))
{
     $('div#footer_toggle').css('display', 'none');
}
```

or

```
if('#toggleDiv').hasClass('hide-me'))
{
     $('div#footer_toggle').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#toggleDiv').hasClass('hide-me')) {
  $('#footer_toggle').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the .hasclass with jquery

```
if ($('#toggleDiv').hasClass('hide-me')){
    $('#footer_toggle').css({'display':'none'});
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

just do this [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
 $('#footer_toggle').toggle($('#toggleDiv').hasClass('hide-me'));
 // by passing in a boolean to toggle() it will hide/show an element
```